# ConEmu： How to get the working directory of the foreground tab?

Tags: conemu

ConEmu experts

I enabled "single instance mode" and had multiple consoles opened as tabs, each with different working directory. I need to write a task that does something in the foreground tab's working directory. But the environmental variable {ConEmuWorkDir} always holds the working directory of the first-created tab, no matter under which tab I invoke the task.

So how to refer to the working directory of the foreground tab?
Could it be accomplished by GuiMacro, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing to have prompt in each tab, you may just use GuiMacro `Print` to paste&run something in your prompt.

Alternatively, you may use `Shell("new_console:I", ...)` to create new tab inheriting current tab environment (including current working folder).

Comment: Thanks Maximus. I try to run  ConEmuC -GuiMacro print "pwd" in a task and want to see it appear after the prompt. But it does not. Instead a new tab opens and displays "OK". What I did wrong here?

Comment: You do not need to run task. Set up hotkey for your macro in the settings. That's all. If you really need to run `print` from outside - use `-GuiMacro:0` command with `-new_console:b` switch.